# Chef - "knife enviroment edit <environment name> from file <json file>" not saving changes

Tags: json, chef-infra, environment

When I try to update an environment attribute in chef using knife like this to pick up the definition from a json file using "from file" it reports "Object unchanged, not saving" even though I have changed an attribute value in my json file:

```
knife environment  --disable-editing edit <environment name> from file environment.json
```

If I remove the  `--disable-editing` option it then invokes the text editor which is not what I want as I need to programatically update the attribute from a script

Any idea what I am missing?

This is Chef: 11.10.4

Answer (score 4):

You want to `upload` the environment:

```
knife environment from file <path>
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked (I did have to force the encoding when writing out the json file in the first place to overcome an error "Yajl::ParseError: lexical error: invalid char in json text.")